# Unable to delete folders and files enclosed pasted to it by other user in a network share

Tags: networking, network-shares, file-permissions, ubuntu-16.04

i am a somewhat new to linux.
i am facing an issue reg my network share permissions.
i am not able to delete directories and enclosed files created by other users in my network share. they all have owner nobody. Group i have been able to stick to the new directories created. but it still have access permission only; not able to delete them which i need to do regularly.
i tried to do quiet a research but could not resolve it. i am using ubuntu 16.04. any help in this regard would be much appreciated.
thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This might not come from Ubuntu itself.

The easiest must be:

```
sudo rm -rf /path_to_my_share/*
```

### If you want to make it permanent

Then you may need to investigate on [how to set a sticky bit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79395/how-does-the-sticky-bit-work). This could be something like:

```
sudo chown my_user /path_to_my_share/* 
sudo chmod 1750 /path_to_my_share/*
```

Comment: well i am looking for somewhat permanent solution like inheriting parent permission to directories and file created by other users in my network share. it is not one time job. it is a regular affair. so any idea???

Comment: i have also tried chown and chmod recursively. guid i set. it is sticking but not the permissions to the newly created to the directories and files enclosed in them. even if gid sticks permission is only of access.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest workaround i have found is as follows.

i went to network >> to my computer >> to my shared directory >> bookmarked

i didn't have to change any permission. there is no issue.

i can write/delete/create files or directories without any issue.